# Ionic importing ScreenOrientation makes the app blank

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have a simple problem. Whenever I import ScreenOrientation from Ionic, my app turns into a blank white screen on my emulator:

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';

  constructor(
    //private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation,
    private platform: Platform
  ) { }
```

Whenever I uncomment that first import and try to build and run, my Ionic app goes blank. I've sequentially commented out every other element in the component and narrowed it down to this issue. Can anyone answer why it does this?

EDIT: package.json below

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.4",
    "@capacitor/android": "^4.6.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "^4.6.1",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^4.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.4.1",
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "^4.6.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.5"
  }
}
```

Providers in app.module.ts:

```
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptorService,
      multi: true},
    ScreenOrientation,
    { 
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy, 
      useClass: IonicRouteStrategy 
    }
    ]
```

Comment: Please post your package.json. Have you installed screen-orientation?

Comment: @E.Maggini updated post w/ package.json. Yes it is installed

Comment: Did you add it to your NgModule, providers array in app.module.ts?

Comment: from where did you install it?? please check docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation

Comment: added the providers section of app.module.ts. reinstalled from the link sent to me. It is still giving the same error.

Comment: Re-read the docs. You are missing the actual cordova plugin `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation && 
npm install @ionic-native/screen-orientation`.  https://www.positronx.io/ionic-screen-orientation-tutorial-with-examples/

Comment: Also please don't post code fragments. App.module.ts should be posted in its entirety. Could be there something missing in your imports....but we wouldn't know.